# Get the parent of the validated input using the input class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, validation

I have the following piece of code to validate if it's empty or not.

```
$(".req").each(function(){
           $(this).validate(formValidate, {
               isNot: new Array("")

           });
            $(this).validateError(function(form, e){
                form.preventDefault();

                $(e).css("background-color", "red");

            });

            $(this).valid(function(form, e){

                $(e).css("background-color", "white");
            });
        });
```

**Notes:**

1. .req is the class I gave to validate if it is a required field
2. isNot + the new Array("") stands for that the value can't be empty
3. $(e).css will change the input background-color to red if the input
   is indeed empty, else(valid) it will just be white

Now my question is as followed: How can I add a text as error? I have tried .append() or .appendTo() but this will just fill the value in the input element and not somewhere on the screen.

I have tried something like this:

```
    var getElement = document.getElementsByClassName(this); //This is still the .req
    $(getElement).parent().append();
    var testAppend = "Tester 123";
    $(testAppend).appendTo($(getElement).parent());
```

But I am not getting it to work..

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
Sorry for unclarity, I shall explain it a bit better:

I have something going on like this:

```
        <p>Firstname</p>
        <p><input type="text" class="req name" /></p>
```

Now what I am trying to do is to append above or below the input on a $(this).validateError function, I am using the class so I should get the element(That's why I used .getElementsByClassName)

The JavaScript file:

$('#form').submit(function(form){
    var formValidate = new Validate;

```
$(".req").each(function(){
   $(this).validate(formValidate, {
       isNot: new Array("")

   });
    $(this).validateError(function(form, e){
        form.preventDefault();

        $(e).css("background-color", "red");
        var getElement = document.getElementsByClassName(this);
        $(getElement).parent().append();
        var testAppend = "Tester 123";
        $(getElement).parent().append(testAppend);


      });

      $(this).valid(function(form, e){

           $(e).css("background-color", "white");
       });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood at all what you were trying to do, but try with this:

```
$(this).parent().append("Tester 123");
```

Comment: Got it working now, just had to replace "this" with my "e". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This will append the text in `testAppend` to the DOM element that is the parent of `getElement`:

```
$(getElement).parent().append(testAppend);
```